# Retrieve multilingual data (Chinese, Japanese...) from SQL Server 2008 R2 and display in Java webapp

Tags: unicode, utf-8, sql-server-2008-r2, multilingual, collation

I have Chinese data in my db and I need to display it in my Java web app. However I am getting **???** as output.

**Database Used:** SQL Server 2008 R2 (`nvarchar` datatype is used in order to support Unicode data and db is created with default collation name i.e.  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and there is no problem while storing the data in db).

**Development Environment:** Window 7

Treegrid is used to display data.

I have already:

```
1. set charset and pageEncoding to UTF-8  in my HTML, jsp and Java
pages.

2.  Updated my jdbc connection  with useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=UTF-8;.

3.  Configured Tomcat’s server.xml connector to use UTF-8 (URIEncoding="UTF-8").
```

I have once set `collation_name` to `Latin1_General_CI_AI` still it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

`Latin1_General_CI_AI` --> There's part of your problem. Latin1 has nothing to do with Unicode. Getting "???" means there's an encoding problem somewhere in your toolchain, where your UTF-8 data gets scrambled into another encoding.

Comment: I have come across an article that sql server 2008 R2 supports Unicode by providing nchar/nvarchar/ntext datatype. But it doesn't support utf-8 encoding for unicode data,however it supports utf-16(as it internally supports UCS-2 and storage format of utf-16 and ucs-2 are similar).Well eclipse doesnt support ucs-2 encoding. Does that i mean that i have to convert my java webapp encoding to utf-16? I even tried with utf-16 format, still ??? are coming.

Comment: As you said, there was some encoding problem in my code.. now it is working fine.. Thanks